# Autocomplete does't work properly in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller: welcome.php

```
public function lookup()
{
    $keyword = trim($_GET['term']);
    $data['response'] = 'false';
    $query = $this->Main_tutorial->lookup($keyword);
    print_r($query);
    if( ! empty($query) )  
    {  
        $data['response'] = 'true';
        $data['message'] = array();  
        $data['auto_com'] = array();  
        foreach( $query as $row )  
        {  
            $data['message'][] = array('tutorial_name' => $row['tutorial_name']);
            $data['auto_com'][] = $row['tutorial_name'];   
        }  
    }  
    if('IS_AJAX')  
    {  
        echo json_encode($data['auto_com']);
    }  
    else 
    {  
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
}
```

view: index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="search-bg__text" name="tutorial_name" id="tutorial_name">
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#tutorial_name").autocomplete({
                source:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/lookup",
                minLength:1,
                select:function(b,c)
                {
                    var a=c.item.value;
                    a=encodeURIComponent(a);
                    location.href=a+"-tutorial";
                    return false
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

model: Main_tutorial.php

```
public function lookup($keyword)
{
    $this->db->select('tutorial_name')->from('tutorial'); 
    $this->db->like('tutorial_name',$keyword,'after');  
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();     
    return $result;
}
```

In this code I want to create an autocomplete suggestion box using codeigniter. Now what happen when I write something inside the tutorial_name input field and inspect the element then select network and click on link it show me the output but can't see on display I don't know why ?. So how can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: remove `print_r($query);` from `lookup()` in controller

Comment: Now it work what was that @B.Desai why print_r($query); hide data.

Comment: And `if('IS_AJAX')` is __always__ `true`

Comment: I have explain all in my answer @omkara check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `autocomplete()` you need output as **json** format. Here you are printing json data with `echo json_encode($data['auto_com']);` But before it you are also displaying data `print_r($query);`. Which create invalid json output. so you have to remove it. Also note that your `if('IS_AJAX')` will always become `true`

```
public function lookup()
{
    $keyword = trim($_GET['term']);
    $data['response'] = 'false';
    $query = $this->Main_tutorial->lookup($keyword);
    if( ! empty($query) )  
    {  
        $data['response'] = 'true';
        $data['message'] = array();  
        $data['auto_com'] = array();  
        foreach( $query as $row )  
        {  
            $data['message'][] = array('tutorial_name' => $row['tutorial_name']);
            $data['auto_com'][] = $row['tutorial_name'];   
        }  
    }  
    if('IS_AJAX')  //This condition always become true
    {  
        echo json_encode($data['auto_com']);
    }  
    else 
    {  
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
}
```